# query builder to postgresql like MS ACCESS

Tags: pgadmin-4

Sometime I use Query builder from MS ACCESS to create the query to PgAdmin.
Is there any tool like MS ACCESS to build query to Postgresql?

Tks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 3rd party tool such as http://razorsql.com/features/postgresql_query_builder.html